# Stuck with multiple conditions and comparing strings

Tags: vba, excel

I have code which creates a summary table from a bunch of excel files. The code copies and uses xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd to paste the selected range from each files to a temporary sheet.

The summary table has 2 input cells which determines the conditions. The 1st cell contains the statuses which can be [ALL, 0,1,2,3,4,5]. The 2nd field is the date in yyyy/mm/dd format.

The first cell recommended to fill, the second is optional. If the 2nd cell is empty then the date is doesn’t matter.

I think I have some trouble comparing the dates or probably the conditions incorrect. For comparing the dates I used two functions: LIKE and StrComp, but none of them worked or maybe because of the incorrect condition.
Please help me how to fix this code:

Set input cell text to string variable (2016.07 = 7 chars with dots):

```
'Get input date as string
  AstrDate = OutputWs.Range("P5").Text
'Set the date to year and month format
  AstrDateChars = Left$(strDate, 7)
```

Decide if the cell is blank:

```
'if the input range is blank then rangeBlank is true
  If IsEmpty(OutputWs.Range("P5")) = True Then
    rangeBlank = True
  Else
    rangeBlank = False
  End If


'Get the output date to compare with
BstrDate = oNewBook.Sheets(1).Range("R22").Text
```

Get the output value:

```
'Set the compared date to year and month format
BstrDateChars = Left$(strDate, 7)
```

Comparing with StrComp function and store value into a boolean variable:

```
'compare date strings
'compareResult = StrComp(AstrDateChars, BstrDateChars, vbBinaryCompare)
```

Comparing with Like function:

```
compareResult = AstrDateChars Like BstrDateChars
```

The conditions:

```
'Which IL status you want to copy?
If inputValue = "ALL" And rangeBlank = True Then                                                   'Search for all IL status
    oNewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("G25:N28").Copy
    tempWS.Range("G25:N28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    oNewBook.Close
ElseIf inputValue = outputValue And rangeBlank = True Then                                         'Search for only the selected IL status
    oNewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("G25:N28").Copy
    tempWS.Range("G25:N28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    oNewBook.Close


ElseIf inputValue = "ALL" And rangeBlank = False And compareResult = True Then                            'Searcg ALL IL status and date
    oNewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("G25:N28").Copy
    tempWS.Range("G25:N28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    oNewBook.Close
ElseIf inputValue = "ALL" And rangeBlank = False And compareResult = False Then                           'Searcg ALL IL status and date, If date does not match, then closes the document
    oNewBook.Close


ElseIf inputValue = outputValue And rangeBlank = False And compareResult = True Then                      'Search for the selected IL0-IL5 and date
    oNewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("G25:N28").Copy
    tempWS.Range("G25:N28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    oNewBook.Close
ElseIf inputValue = outputValue And rangeBlank = False And compareResult = False Then                     'Search for the selected IL0-IL5 and date, if date does not match, then closes the document
    oNewBook.Close
End If
```

Comment: "none of them worked" is not very helpful. What does not work? Does it give an unexpected result? Does it give an error? If so, what message and which line? Does Excel crash or become unresponsive? Does Windows crash?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct No errors. It just does not recognizing the conditions. For example: I made a test with IL 4 status and 2013.08 and it copied all the IL 4 status, not the IL 4 with 2013.08 date

Comment: Did you `Dim` `compareResult` and `rangeBlank` as boolean? Can you verify that the problem is indeed the string comparison by trying it with actual strings? You can also step through the code using F8 and check if the values are set as you expect.

Comment: you're always using `strDate` (`AstrDateChars = Left$(strDate, 7)` and `BstrDateChars = Left$(strDate, 7)`) where I'd say you should use, respectively, `AstrDate ` and `BstrDate `

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Dim rangeBlank As Boolean Dim compareResult As Boolean Dim AstrDate As String Dim AstrDateChars As String Dim BstrDate As String Dim BstrDateChars As String

Comment: @user3598756 That might be a problem. I corrected it, made a test. It seems to be good, but now it does not closes the excel files.

Comment: that should have solved the _"It just does not recognizing the conditions"_ issue. As for the _not closing workbook_ one you'd better post a new question with proper details (code) as to when and how are those  workbook opened and treated

Comment: @user3598756 Thank you to warning me with the strDate. I fixed it and now works fine. Also I put an else statement to the end which closes the document. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome. but you accepted an answer which didn't point you to what I told you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for StrComp:

```
compareResult = (StrComp(AstrDateChars, BstrDateChars, vbBinaryCompare)=0)
```

Comment: from comments: "strDate (AstrDateChars = Left$(strDate, 7) and BstrDateChars = Left$(strDate, 7)) where I'd say you should use, respectively, AstrDate and BstrDate "